# how to call fail method into jquery.get/post success method?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, get

how can i call a fail method into an ajax callback success method? for example when i get some date from server, i have to say this data does not ok. for this i use below codes:

```
Loading.show();
$.post(_api_server+"sign/in.php",opt,function(gets){
    try{
            if(gets.success){  
                Toast.show("success!!!","succ"); 
            }else{ 
                // duplicate codes
                Loading.hide();
                Toast.show("not Ok!!!");
            }
    }catch(e){
        // duplicate codes
        Loading.hide();
        Toast.show("not Ok!!!");
    } 
}).fail(function(){
    // duplicate codes
    Loading.hide();
    Toast.show("not Ok!!!");
});
```

as you see, i use duplicate codes for do a thing. i want to use something like this:

```
Loading.show();
$.post(_api_server+"sign/in.php",opt,function(gets){
    try{
            if(gets.success){  
                Toast.show("success!!!","succ"); 
            }else{ 
                this.fail();
            }
    }catch(e){
        this.fail();
    } 
}).fail(function(){
    Loading.hide();
    Toast.show("not Ok!!!");
});
```

how can i do this? is there any way for it?

--update

i have many ajax with diffrent fail methods, i can not use other / outside function.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply put your duplicated code in a single function. If u define it as a non-anonimous function, or you reference your anonimous function through a variable you will be able to call it from anywhere.

```
var failedRequest = function(){
    Loading.hide();
    Toast.show("not Ok!!!");
};

Loading.show();
$.post(_api_server+"sign/in.php",opt,function(gets){
    try{
            if(gets.success){  
                Toast.show("success!!!","succ"); 
            }else{ 
                failedRequest();
            }
    }catch(e){
        failedRequest();
    } 
}).fail(failedRequest);
```

Comment: hi thank you for answering , but i know this, i have many ajax with diffrent fail method, i can not use this.

Comment: @saleh Hello! Apologies for not knowing how to resolve your question.
I'm not sure if is possible to invoke the fail method from the success callback.

Maybe if you don't found an alternative (if the jQuery API doesn't expose in any way the fail method), you can define your fail method in a variable (not necessarilly as I specified in my answer) and call it from the success function.